# Setting formatter callback using highcharts-convert.js

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts-convert.js to create PDF charts on the serverside. I want to set the dataLabel formatter for a column chart (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.dataLabels). As this is a function, I can't write it in my output json file that is the input for highcharts-convert.js. So I assume I need to put it in my callback.js and call it like:

highcharts-convert.js -infile infile.js -outfile outfile.pdf -width 1000 -callback callback.js

But I can't set the formatter function in callback.js. I tried this:

```
function( chart ) {
    var labelFormatter = function(p) {
        if (this.y == 0) {
            return '';
        }
        else {
            return this.y
        }
    };

    chart.series.dataLabels.formatter = labelFormatter;
}
```

But that gives me this error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'chart.series.dataLabels.formatter = labelFormatter')
```

I tried putting the formatter function outside the definition of the callback, but highcharts-convert.js won't accept that. How do I set a dataLabel formatter callback for highcharts-convert.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, input file for Highcharts exporting server doesn't have to be true JSON. In general, function in that JSON are supported. Just use that as example:

```
{"series": [{"data": [29.9, 71.5, 106.4], "dataLabels": { "enabled": true, "formatter":function(p) {if (this.y == 0) {return '';} else {return this.y+'a';}}}}]}
```

Comment: That didn't work either; I got "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'd.formatter.call(l,d)')". Did that work for you using highcharts-convert.js? See my edit, above.

Comment: Sorry, my previous update had a syntax error in it. It is important to NOT wrap the function body in quotes. This is an acceptable answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you use callback function at serverside, Use this.

```
   function (chart) { 

      options = chart.options;



      var labelFormatter = function() {
        if (this.y == 0) return ''; 
        else return this.y;
      }

      options.yAxis[0].labels = new Object();
      options.yAxis[0].labels.formatter = labelFormatter;
      chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); 

      chart.redraw();
```

}